# constexpr function and its parameter

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
constexpr int hello(int j) {
    return j * 12;
}

constexpr int bye(int j = 6) {
    return j * 12;
}

int main() {
    int i = 6;
    constexpr int a1 = hello(i); //error
    constexpr int a2 = hello(6); //ok
    constexpr int a3 = hello(int(6)); //ok
    constexpr int a4 = bye(); //ok
    constexpr int a5 = bye(i); //error
    constexpr int a6 = bye(6); //ok
    return 0;
}
```

What's difference between `hellow(i)` and `hello(6)`? I think one is `int j = i;` and j is not a constexpr, while the other is `int j = 6` and j is still not a constexpr, both j are `int` type.
**int * literal != constexpr**, so the return type is not a constexpr.

I got the above conclusion from an example in the book：
`int staff_size = 27; //staff_size is not a const expression`

> Although staff_size is initialized from a literal, it is not a constant expression
>   because it is a plain int, not a const int.

Moreover, I notice that `hello(int(6))` works fine too, what's the "thing" here?

Additionally, `bye()` works while `hello(i)` does not, both parameter are initialized inside the function, only one with default value, what's the point here?

Very confused, hope someone could explain :D

PS: have no idea to figure out a better title, sorry for that

Comment: constexpr-ness propagates. `6` is constant, `i` is not. It isn't enough you didn't modify it, you need to declare it.

Comment: An `int` literal *IS* a constant expression. And `int(6)` has the same semantics as the `int` literal `6` (both an rvalue).

Comment: @PasserBy if it's really "propagates". Then why this doesnt work? 
`constexpr int j1 = 6; int q = j1; constexpr int j2 = q; ` It should be fine since j1's constexpr-ness propagates to q, then q should be able to intialized another constexpr.

Comment: That's loosely speaking. I meant constexpr functions have constexpr value iff it's parameters are constexpr. `q is initialized by a constant doesn't mean `q` is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to note here is that the compiler "validates" the code, it doesn't "read" it.

The compiler expects all parts of a constexpr to be a known valid constant at compile time. So although you and I know, from reading the code, that the value of `i` never changes, the compiler doesn't "know" it unless you declare `i` to be a constant. As far as it is concerned you could have executed other code somewhere to change the value of `i`.

In all the cases where the function is called without the `i`, the compiler knows for a fact, without a doubt, that the value of `j` is a constant integer with a value of `6`, (note: `int(6)` is the same as just `6`).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `hello(6)` and `hello(i)` is that the `6` in `hello(6)` is a `constexpr` function parameter, while the `i` in the `hello(i)` is a regular `int` parameter.

If you declare `i` to be `constexpr int i = 6;`, then `hello(i)` will compile and execute.

In `hello(int(6))`, you're saying cast `6`, an integer literal, into an int. This is a redundant operation. `hello(int(6))` and `hello(6)` will have similar, if not identical behavior.

`bye()` works since the function parameter uses the default parameter (the `j = 6` in `constexpr int bye(int j = 6);`). The default initialized parameter is known at compile time, thus, is a `constexpr` by definition